# Getting CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException while using Sqlite DB

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm using this code to get the count from the cursor. On executing the Select query in SQLite Manager I am getting count as 6.

```
public int getCount(String name){           
        Cursor cursor;
        cursor = myDataBase.rawQuery(
                "select count(*) as _count from tProviderNode where parentId IN(select identifier from tProviderNode where name='"
                        + name + "');", null);
        return cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_count"));
    }
```

On execution of this function I'm getting the following error:-

```
android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1
```

Why I'm getting this error? Am I missing anything.

Comment: may be your name is not matching with the db-column's value, it may be possible that your db-col contains white space.

Comment: a little search before asking the question would have given you the answer in no time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `cursor.moveToFirst()` before you use the `Cursor`:

```
// ...
cursor.moveToFirst();
return cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_count"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Call cursor.moveToFirst() to fix the issue.